# Running multiple interactive cluster jobs from python, and waiting for them to finish

Tags: python, multiprocessing, cluster-computing

I'm looking for the best solution for the following problem:
I'm working on a cluster, and I'd like to spawn interactive jobs to the cluster.
However, I'd like to spawn about 7,000 of these jobs, and I wouldn't be able to run them in parallel.

I would like to have a pool of processes / threads, that would run jobs interactively (say, 4 at a time), and I'd like my program to "wait" for all the 7,000 jobs to finish running.

Would that require a queue in addition to the thread pool?
What is the best approach to achieve my goal?
This is the code I have at the moment.

```
results = []
with open(input_file_location, "r") as input_file:
    log("Spawnning jobs")

    for filename in input_file:
        cmd = config.command_templates["some_cmd"] % (filename)
        results.append(pool.apply_async(run_job, (cmd,)))

# Close the pool and wait for each running task to complete
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Comment: `apply_async` has a queue associated with it. https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply_async

Comment: Not sure I get your question. The code you posted seems correct, so where is the problem? You don't need any additional queue as the Pool uses one internally to de-couple your execution from the workers one.